# Are Feather Teasers used for all mounts?

Tags: ni-no-kuni-cross-worlds

I've only unlocked the Catarumpus mount so far, and I have quite a few Feather Teasers, the material used for training it.  However, I'd rather not use them all if this same resource is going to be needed to train another mount.  So, do multiple mounts use the same upgrading resource?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, I am pretty sure all mounts use the same resources for an upgrade attempt:

> To power up your mounts in Ni no Kuni: Cross Worlds you need Feather Teaser and 600 Gold each time.

How to boost the chances for upgrade success? I don't know.

Comment: "attempt"... Does it have a chance to fail?

Comment: @Malady Yes.  So far I've only seen 70% chance at success.  Not sure if it changes.